# Type properties to discriminated union types

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types, mapped-types

I'd like to transform a type to a discriminated union type:

```js
type Current = {
  A : number,
  B : string,
}
```

to

```js
type Target= {
  type: 'A',
  value: number
}
| {
  type: 'B',
  value: string
}
```

So that I can discriminate the result.

```js
function handle(result: ToTarget<Current>) {
 switch(result.type){
  case 'A':
   return result.value // number
  case 'B':
   return result.value // string
 } 
}
```

The closest I got was:

```js
type ToTargetA<U> = { code: keyof U, value : U[keyof U] } 
// code and value are not in sync so code is 'A | B' and value is 'number | string' but discriminating on code does not narrow value.

type ToTargetB<U, K extends keyof U = any> = { code: keyof K, value : U[K] }
// requires me to specify K as a generic parameter which is not what I want.
```

I tried several conditional type expressions but couldn't get much closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
type ToDiscriminatedUnion<T, KK extends PropertyKey, VK extends PropertyKey> =
  { [K in keyof T]: { [P in KK | VK]: P extends KK ? K : T[K] } }[keyof T];
```

You can verify that it produces the type you want:

```
type Target = ToDiscriminatedUnion<Current, 'type', 'value'>;
/* type Target = {
    type: "A";
    value: number;
} | {
    type: "B";
    value: string;
} */
```

The approach here is to build a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with the same keys `K` as in your original object type `T`, but whose values are the `{type: T, value: T[K]}` types you want in the discriminated union.  This type ends up becoming `{A: {type: "A", value: number}, B: {type: "B". value: string}}`.

Then we can [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the union of its property values by indexing into it with `[keyof T]`, producing the desired `{type: "A", value: string} | {type: "B", value: number}` discriminated union.

---

The only extra thing I did there was to make it so you could specify what keys to give to the original key names (`KK`, being `"type"` in your case) and the original value names (`VK`, being `"value"` in your case).  If you don't want to change that ever, you can hardcode it:

```
type ToDiscriminatedUnion<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: { type: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T];

type Target = ToDiscriminatedUnion<Current>;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdsKBeKBvAUFKAQQC4oU4BbAIwgQBp8oAhUgZ2AQEsUBzBgX1y5QkKABUA9gBFOrAMZcK3AIbAIAEwCqKThJQAeMXSgBpE1AgAPNSnWsoABQQTICUCYghjANXNWbdo7Oru6eAHyYjNhQANrm3FAA1p4SAGbiALqk0TEOUAlmUAA+UL5ZjhbWqIGFAPymUKRicRlQ-G0xySBpmQDcQiLQYsoIPBDoWJIy8ooqalo6evrwSKjAxgDkgxubAG7KADZwEBth-QD0AFRQg+IjYxM4jASDpABEhG-9BAT7RxCkcjUWi9KC4dolPA-G7gAFQN5ML7PKB-Y5sDjcHj9dqXc5CYSw8TSWQKThKFCqDTaXQoABMhgiGCisXiKCSKXSYnK0VepmMqLhzRMrXa-E6HL6A0Jw1G41pmCJ01J5MpCxp9JWyDQZ1wVxhohlD3lWChP15HyR0IFgMoNAQ2OKT2h5sR3x+1qg7C4vAduNwQA)

Comment: Great answer! `[keyof T]` at the end is mystery piece I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but wondering if there is a cleaner/better solution.

```js
type DistributedProperties<T> = { [P in keyof T] : { code: P, value: T[P]} } 
type Union<T> = DistributedProperties<T>[keyof DistributedProperties<T>]
```